# jquery - queue event until ajax call finishes

Tags: javascript, jquery

im working with rails and jquery here.

When the email field loses focus (blur), i call server to verify if it is valid (email format and unique). If it is valid, i update a hidden input value to true and false if it is not valid.

Then user clicks (focus) on another email field, if the first email is invalid (hidden input false) i disable this field and send some alert message.

My problem is, user types an email on the first email field, it is a valid email so on blur i update the hidden field but if the user clicks on the second email field just after typing the first email, the focus event on the second field is triggered before the hidden input gets updated and the second email field is disabled wrongly.

basically i need to queue the focus event until the ajax call is finished

Sorry its a little confusing to explain, if someone understand what i said, is there a workaround?

Comment: I wouldn't disable the second field. It should be pretty clear once the first field fails that the second is not valid either. If you like this user paradigm, then I would provide some sort of modal feedback window. (Validating... ... ).

Comment: but i cant allow user to proceed if the first field is not valid. He needs to type right the first so he can access the second.

Comment: I agree, it sounds like the design is flawed here. You should probably either (1) keep the second field hidden or (2) keep it disabled until you get the response from the server. Also, let the user know that something is happening until the request comes back from the server.

Comment: Or disable it from the start, and put a button next to the first field that says something like 'Validate'. If it comes back not valid, nothing changes and the user is notified. If valid, the first field is disabled and the second enabled.

Comment: i came accross with something like abdullah suggested. When 1 gets focused i show an overlay div on 2 and hides it when 1 finishes the validation with ajax, this way the user can only click on 2 after ajax finishes.

Comment: can you tell us what type of form is this? is this a registration form? or an add contacts form? etc. we could suggest alternative methods rather than hiding the next input.